Page not refreshing after task creation/update
I'm working on a Next.js project with Drizzle ORM where I can create and update tasks. After submitting the task form, I get navigated back to the homepage, but the new/updated task isn't displayed until I manually refresh the page. Here’s the relevant code:
TaskForm.tsx (Client Component):
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
  const response = 
    type === OperationType.Create 
      ? await addTask(values) 
      : await updateTask(defaultValues?.id ?? 0, { ...defaultValues, ...values });

  toast(response.message);

  if (response.success) {
    form.reset();
    router.refresh(); // Trying to refresh the page
    router.push(redirect ?? "/"); // Redirect to homepage after submission
  }
};

app/page.tsx (Server Component):
export const revalidate = 0; // Disable ISR

export default async function Home() {
  const tasks = await getTasks();
  const completedTasks = tasks.filter(task => task.isCompleted);
  const incompleteTasks = tasks.filter(task => !task.isCompleted);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Incomplete Tasks</h1>
      <TodoListTable data={incompleteTasks} />
      <h1>Completed Tasks</h1>
      <CompletedListTable data={completedTasks} />
    </div>
  );
}

actions.ts (Server Actions for Drizzle ORM):
export async function addTask(task) {
  try {
    db.insert(tasks).values(task).run();
    return { success: true, message: "Task created successfully" };
  } catch (error) {
    return { success: false, message: "Error creating task" };
  }
}

The task is created or updated successfully, but when the page navigates back to the homepage, I don't see the new task unless I manually refresh the page.
What I've Tried:

I’ve used router.refresh() to refetch the page, but it doesn't seem to update the homepage's data after task submission.
I disabled ISR using export const revalidate = 0; in app/page.tsx to make sure that fresh data is fetched every time.
Tried both router.replace() and router.push() but no difference in behavior.

What am I missing? How can I ensure the homepage always reflects the updated task list after submission without a manual refresh?

This is due to cached data.
We can change on demand by revalidatePath function.
I have same problem and solved using this function in my project .
You can refer this in nextJs docs.
